# Basic nested radical question $ \sqrt{y\sqrt{y}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First-time asker here. I'm an old guy, going back to college, and I'm in College Algebra. I've run across a problem that I can't match up with the answer that the back of the book (or Wolfram Alpha, or Symbolab) gives.

Here's the problem:

"Use positive exponents to rewrite:  $ \sqrt{y\sqrt{y}} $ "

The answer is supposed to be $ y^{3/4} $, but I can not get it there no matter what I do.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Barnisinko

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$\sqrt{y\sqrt{y}}=(y\times y^{1/2})^{1/2}=(y^{3/2})^{1/2}=y^{3/4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\sqrt{y}=y^{1/2}$ so that:
$$y\sqrt{y}=y\cdot y^{1/2}=y^{1+1/2}=y^{3/2}$$
Using again that the square root is the same as a half exponent, we get
$$\sqrt{y\sqrt{y}}=\big(y\sqrt{y}\big)^{1/2}=\big(y^{3/2}\big)^{1/2}=y^{(3/2)\cdot (1/2)}=y^{3/4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $\sqrt{x} = x^{\frac 1 2}$:

$$ \sqrt{y\sqrt{y}} =  (y(y)^{\frac 1 2})^{\frac 1 2} =  ((y)^{\frac 3 2})^{\frac 1 2} = y^{\frac 3 4} $$

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You don't need to say thank you, just upvote the answer if it was helpful.